# Multiple carousel sliders on one page not working

Tags: javascript, webflow

I'm trying to add multiple automatically generated product sliders from CMS Collections to different pages on Webflow using custom JS. The first slider of each page works but the second one doesn't.

From reading on here I think I need to make a slightly different function for the second and third sliders or put each instance into an array but I'm very new to JS and can't work out what to change.

HTML code is taken from inspecting element as I can't export code from Webflow.

Help much appreciated

[image: Here is the HTML and CSS as on Webflow]

JS

```
<script>
/*  Left/Right Arrow Styling  */
function leftArrowHide() {
    $("#left-arrow").removeClass('arrow-box').addClass('arrow-end');
}

function leftArrowShow() {
    $("#left-arrow").removeClass('arrow-end').addClass('arrow-box');
}

function rightArrowHide() {
    $("#right-arrow").removeClass('arrow-box').addClass('arrow-end');
}

function rightArrowShow() {
    $("#right-arrow").removeClass('arrow-end').addClass('arrow-box');
}
/*  Hide the CMS nav dots used for styling
and set the arrows to default styles for Slide 1  */
$('.navdot').hide();
rightArrowShow();
leftArrowHide();
/*  Generate nav dots for each CMS slide  */
var slideval = 0;
var cmscount = $("#slides").children().length;
var countconverted = (cmscount - 1) * -100;
for (i = 0; i < cmscount; i++) {
    var container = document.getElementById('#nav');
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = 'navdot';
    div.id = 'slide' + i;
    div.className += ' generated';
    var slidenumber = document.createElement("div");
    slidenumber.innerHTML = i + 1;
    slidenumber.className = 'navdot-number';
    div.append(slidenumber);
    document.getElementById('nav').append(div);
}

/*  Activate the generated nav dot for Slide 1. */
$("#slide0").addClass("selected");

/*  Click detection for nav dots. Activate the corresponding slide 
and update the left/right arrows if on the first or last slide  */
$(".navdot").click(function() {
    $(".navdot").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
    var slide = $(this).attr('id');
    var num = slide.replace('slide', '');
    slide = parseInt(num);
    var multiplier = slide * -100;
    slideval = multiplier;
    if (slide == 0) {
        leftArrowHide();
        rightArrowShow();
    } else if (slide == cmscount - 1) {
        rightArrowHide();
        leftArrowShow();
    } else {
        leftArrowShow();
        rightArrowShow();
    }
    moveSlides(slideval);
    $('#animationTrigger').click();
});

/*  Right Arrow click detection and actions. */
$("#right-arrow").click(function() {
    if (slideval > countconverted) {
        leftArrowShow();
        slideval += -100;
        moveSlides(slideval);
        updatenav();
        $('#animationTrigger').click();
        if (slideval == countconverted) {
            rightArrowHide();
        }
    }
});
/*  Left Arrow click detection and actions. */
$("#left-arrow").click(function() {
    if (slideval < 0) {
        rightArrowShow();
        slideval += 100;
        moveSlides(slideval);
        updatenav();
        $('#animationTrigger').click();
        if (slideval == 0) {
            leftArrowHide();
        }
    }
});
/*  Function called on by arrow and nav dot clicks to move to
the selected slide  */
function moveSlides(measurement) {
    $('#slides').css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(' + slideval + '%)',
        '-moz-transform': 'translateX(' + slideval + '%)',
        '-ms-transform': 'translateX(' + slideval + '%)',
        '-o-transform': 'translateX(' + slideval + '%)',
        'transform': 'translateX(' + slideval + '%)'
    });
}
/*  Update nav dots so that the active dot corresponds to the 
active slide  */
function updatenav() {
    $(".navdot").removeClass("selected");
    var slides = $('.generated');
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        var slide = slides[i].id;
        var num = slide.replace('slide', '');
        slide = parseInt(num);
        var multiplier = slide * -100;
        if (multiplier == slideval) {
            $("#slide" + i).addClass("selected");
        }
    }
} 
</script>
```

```
CSS
 .slider-container {
        background-color: transparent;
      }
      .navdot-number {
        color: #000;
      }
      .arrow-end {
        color: #000;
      }
      .arrow {
        border-color: #000;
      }
      .navdot {
        border-color: #000;
      }
      .image-11 {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .product-slide-wrapper {
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-bottom: 100px;
      }
    }

.arrow-container {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0%;
      top: 0%;
      right: 0%;
      bottom: 0%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

HTML for slider1

```
<div class="slider-container">
<div class="arrow-container">
<div id="left-arrow" data-w-id="c0dde25c-5f11-4f92-00cf-87e1df766fdb" class="arrow-end">
<div class="arrow">
<img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ee34a47f5f3055b3c5c6b1c/5ee34a47dc55146960c794d0_Asset%201arrow_white.svg" alt="" class="image-10"></div></div>
<div id="right-arrow" data-w-id="c0dde25c-5f11-4f92-00cf-87e1df766fde" class="arrow-box">
<div class="arrow">
<img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ee34a47f5f3055b3c5c6b1c/5ee34a47dc55146960c794d0_Asset%201arrow_white.svg" alt="" class="image-1"></div></div></div><div class="collection-list-wrapper-2 w-dyn-list"><div id="slides" role="list" class="collection-list-7 w-dyn-items"><div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://www.revolve.com/astr-the-label-sonnet-dress/dp/ASTR-WD131/?d=Womens&amp;page=1&amp;lc=6&amp;itrownum=2&amp;itcurrpage=1&amp;itview=05" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ef111bb51496881a8f415f3_ASTR-WD131_V1.jpg" alt="" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ef111bb51496881a8f415f3_ASTR-WD131_V1-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ef111bb51496881a8f415f3_ASTR-WD131_V1-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ef111bb51496881a8f415f3_ASTR-WD131_V1.jpg 960w" class="image-11"></a></div><div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://shop.nordstrom.com/s/nike-air-force-1-shadow-sneaker-women/5274385?origin=coordinating-5274385-0-1-PDP_1-recbot-visually_similar_type2_no_dresses&amp;recs_placement=PDP_1&amp;recs_strategy=visually_similar_type2_no_dresses&amp;recs_source=recbot&amp;recs_page_type=product&amp;recs_seed=3458988&amp;color=WHITE%2F%20WHITE%2F%20WHITE" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block">
<img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ef10f19b93a055b3ecd3388_0d8b1a67-edcf-4601-91b0-af40acf25215.jpeg" alt="" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ef10f19b93a055b3ecd3388_0d8b1a67-edcf-4601-91b0-af40acf25215-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ef10f19b93a055b3ecd3388_0d8b1a67-edcf-4601-91b0-af40acf25215-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ef10f19b93a055b3ecd3388_0d8b1a67-edcf-4601-91b0-af40acf25215-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ef10f19b93a055b3ecd3388_0d8b1a67-edcf-4601-91b0-af40acf25215.jpeg 1560w" class="image-11"></a></div></div></div>
<div id="nav" class="nav">
<div class="navdot selected" style="display: none;">
<div class="navdot-number">1</div></div>
<div class="navdot" style="display: none;"><div class="navdot-number">1</div></div>
<div class="navdot generated selected" id="slide0" style="display: none;"><div class="navdot-number">1</div></div>
<div class="navdot generated" id="slide1" style="display: none;">
<div class="navdot-number">2</div></div>
<div class="navdot generated" id="slide0" style="display: none;">
<div class="navdot-number">1</div></div><div class="navdot generated" id="slide1" style="display: none;"><div class="navdot-number">2</div></div>
<div class="navdot generated" id="slide0"><div class="navdot-number">1</div></div>
<div class="navdot generated" id="slide1">
<div class="navdot-number">2</div></div></div></div>
```

HTML for slider2

```
<div class="slider-container">
<div class="arrow-container">
<div id="left-arrow" data-w-id="7ae1b364-94b2-034e-386f-77eacfb86758" class="arrow-box">
<div class="arrow">
<img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ee34a47f5f3055b3c5c6b1c/5ee34a47dc55146960c794d0_Asset%201arrow_white.svg" alt="" class="image-10"></div></div>
<div id="right-arrow" data-w-id="7ae1b364-94b2-034e-386f-77eacfb8675b" class="arrow-end"><div class="arrow"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5ee34a47f5f3055b3c5c6b1c/5ee34a47dc55146960c794d0_Asset%201arrow_white.svg" alt="" class="image-1"></div></div></div>
<div class="collection-list-wrapper-2 w-dyn-list">
<div id="slides" role="list" class="collection-list-7 w-dyn-items">
<div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://www.revolve.com/sachajuan-hair-mousse/dp/SAHR-WU14/?d=Womens&amp;_cclid=Google_CjwKCAjwiMj2BRBFEiwAYfTbClKooWZdyyJG_1JGnbhQ0ZFHY1vYWiZc-gG9xEhcDeHtMeEKgVES5BoCzVYQAvD_BwE&amp;countrycode=US&amp;gclid=CjwKCAjwiMj2BRBFEiwAYfTbClKooWZdyyJG_1JGnbhQ0ZFHY1vYWiZc-gG9xEhcDeHtMeEKgVES5BoCzVYQAvD_BwE" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed68a21bf550172a1e8151e_SAHR-WU14_V1.jpg" alt="" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed68a21bf550172a1e8151e_SAHR-WU14_V1-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed68a21bf550172a1e8151e_SAHR-WU14_V1-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed68a21bf550172a1e8151e_SAHR-WU14_V1.jpg 960w" class="image-11"></a></div>
<div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://www.randco.com/outer-space-working-hairspray.html" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed689d049f4936b10c9eb86_E30014015056000-3952706688.jpg" alt="" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed689d049f4936b10c9eb86_E30014015056000-3952706688-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed689d049f4936b10c9eb86_E30014015056000-3952706688-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed689d049f4936b10c9eb86_E30014015056000-3952706688-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed689d049f4936b10c9eb86_E30014015056000-3952706688.jpg 1536w" class="image-11"></a></div><div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://bluemercury.com/products/oribe-gel-serum?variant=26187316806" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed68961023d8e7496a5b8d5_23e2f925-1537-417e-9292-2023db7f3b16.jpeg" alt="" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed68961023d8e7496a5b8d5_23e2f925-1537-417e-9292-2023db7f3b16-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed68961023d8e7496a5b8d5_23e2f925-1537-417e-9292-2023db7f3b16.jpeg 780w" class="image-11"></a></div><div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://us.davines.com/collections/all-products/products/oi-oil" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6773f782d07450dab47aa_76000_OI_Oil_135ml_Davines_2000x.jpg" alt="" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6773f782d07450dab47aa_76000_OI_Oil_135ml_Davines_2000x-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6773f782d07450dab47aa_76000_OI_Oil_135ml_Davines_2000x-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6773f782d07450dab47aa_76000_OI_Oil_135ml_Davines_2000x-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6773f782d07450dab47aa_76000_OI_Oil_135ml_Davines_2000x.jpg 1200w" class="image-11"></a></div><div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://www.randco.com/motorcycle-flexible-gel" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6783c9ce76839126ca58c_motorcycle-pdp.png" alt="" class="image-11"></a></div><div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://www.sephora.com/product/perfect-hair-day-phd-dry-shampoo-P399330" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6799d7720b92d58a6cd6f_s2343051-main-zoom.jpg" alt="" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6799d7720b92d58a6cd6f_s2343051-main-zoom-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6799d7720b92d58a6cd6f_s2343051-main-zoom-p-800.jpeg 800w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6799d7720b92d58a6cd6f_s2343051-main-zoom-p-1080.jpeg 1080w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed6799d7720b92d58a6cd6f_s2343051-main-zoom.jpg 1500w" class="image-11"></a></div><div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://mr-smith.com.au/product/mousse/?v=3a1ed7090bfa" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed679bc16a79a6097df01e7_Screen%20Shot%202020-05-30%20at%205.58.20%20PM.png" alt="" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed679bc16a79a6097df01e7_Screen%20Shot%202020-05-30%20at%205.58.20%20PM-p-500.png 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed679bc16a79a6097df01e7_Screen%20Shot%202020-05-30%20at%205.58.20%20PM-p-800.png 800w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed679bc16a79a6097df01e7_Screen%20Shot%202020-05-30%20at%205.58.20%20PM.png 911w" class="image-11"></a></div><div role="listitem" class="collection-item-6 w-dyn-item"><a href="https://shop.nordstrom.com/s/oribe-dry-texturizing-spray/4511005" class="link-block-5 w-inline-block"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed679f8d0eb7757d18e4907_9f440288-4d4e-4536-8576-91d11f38d562.jpeg" alt="" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed679f8d0eb7757d18e4907_9f440288-4d4e-4536-8576-91d11f38d562-p-500.jpeg 500w, https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5eaea74b29a4a6770490a38b/5ed679f8d0eb7757d18e4907_9f440288-4d4e-4536-8576-91d11f38d562.jpeg 1560w" class="image-11"></a></div></div></div>
<div id="nav" class="nav">
<div class="navdot selected" style="display: none;">
<div class="navdot-number">1</div></div>
<div class="navdot" style="display: none;">
<div class="navdot-number">1</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS (if any) as well

Comment: You must consider that there is the value of an `id` attribute must be unique. If you have more than one element with the same id, JavaScript will only match the first one.

Comment: I added the HTML taken from inspecting the element on Safari. I can add custom JS but cannot edit or access HTML or CSS code on Webflow, only edit them in the visual designer.

Comment: Please add the code of two sliders and the CSS of all the relevant classes and ids

Comment: I've added the HMTL of both sliders and CSS

Comment: I think your code is still incomplete. When I try to make a running example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/c2d6fcee132995f7c8e0460505b1477e?editors=0110), even the first slider doesn't work

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. I can't export the HTML and CSS as it is Webflow, only have direct access to the JS. I think the issue is that I'm running the same function twice and it's only working on the first slider and not moving on to the second. Would there be no way of figuring out what to change without seeing the HTML and CSS? See the image I attached which includes the HTML and CSS Classes and Ids.

Comment: I don't know anything about webflow. But it is your duty to provide for all the necessary code to show us your issue. If you don't show al  your code then it will be very difficult for us to help you. My advise: Go somewhere like Codepen, jsfiddle and the likes. Post your HTML, JS, CSS code in there; Strip down your code to the most necessary things. Then you can link to that pen/fiddle here

Answer (score 0):

`id` field must be unique in the DOM.

In this reduced example, taken from your code, only the first element with the same id will be colored in red.

```js
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
nav.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```html
<div id="nav">nav 1</div>
<div id="nav">nav 2</div>
```

Also, the correct syntax is `getElementById('id')` where the element has `id="id"` so without `#`